# How can I add a menu item to the right click menu?

Tags: command-line, menu, elinks

In Terminal, if I right-click over a URL, a little menu pops up. The first option is "Open Link".

Is there any way to add an option to this menu called "Open Link in Elinks"? I'd like to be able to choose that open and then either launch a new terminal window with elinks or open the URL in elinks in the same window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Nautilus-Actions Configuration tool. It should be available in the software center and Synaptic. follow this link for more info. http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/368016-nautilus-actions-extend-the-functionality-and-flexibility-of-the-file-manager

Answer (score 1):

It uses the xdg-open, it will open with the default browser.