# How to integrate "run as shell script" in right click menu of file manager?

Tags: command-line, scripts, filemanager, sh, csh

Now when I want to run a shell script (.sh or .csh file), I need to right click the file manager and click "open terminal here", then type "./xxx.sh" to run the shell script file. It is very inconvenient for me. However is there any way to integrate "run as shell script when I right click any flat text file"?

Here are the File Manager I use most frequently:
Thunar (in Xfce4), PCManFM (in LXDE) and Nautilus(in Gnome).

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify which file manager you're using – at least [SpaceFM](https://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/) has this feature by default.

Comment: @dessert, I have added them at the bottom of my post.

Comment: I think you should ask that question for one single piece of software at a time. For Thunar you can find a related question (or possible duplicate) [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/876567/507051), for PCManFM [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/936896/507051) and for Nautilus [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/21953/507051) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/215370/507051).

Comment: @dessert, Sorry for that, I just considered that they have same configure framework.

Answer (score 4):

#### Right click to run script in Nautilus

Here is how I setup this script: [Nautilus can set desktop wallpaper. How can it set login and lock screen wallpaper?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871312/nautilus-can-set-desktop-wallpaper-how-can-it-set-login-and-lock-screen-wallpap).

After using Nautilus to navigate and view an appropriate .png or .jpg file to use as login screen and lock screen wallpaper, Nautilus can set this for you using a script.

To create the script use:

```
cd ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
gedit set-login-wallpaper
```

Paste in these lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## Set login wallpaper

# strip new line char passed by Nautilus
FILENAME=$(echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | sed -e 's/\r//g')

# Multiple files can't be selected.
LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l <<< "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
LINE_COUNT=$((LINE_COUNT-1))

if [[ $LINE_COUNT > 1 ]] ; then
    zenity --error --text "Ony one file can be selected at a time! "
    exit 1
fi

# Object type must be "file..." (ie no directories, etc.)
if [ -d "${FILENAME}" ] ; then
    zenity --error --text "$FILENAME is a directory!";
    exit 1
else
    if [ -f "${FILENAME}" ]; then
        : # Bash noop
    else
        zenity --error --text "${FILENAME} is not a file!";
        exit 2
    fi
fi

# Build working file in /tmp
echo "[com.canonical.unity-greeter]" > /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp
echo "draw-user-backgrounds=false" >> /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp
echo "background='$FILENAME'" >> /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp

# Must run as sudo
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ] ; then

    # Get sudo password
    PASSWORD=$(zenity --password --title="Set Login Wallpaper" --timeout=20)

    # copy working file to real file using sudo
    echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S cp /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp \
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override

    # compile using sudo
    echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas

else
    # Already sudo so simply copy and compile
    # copy working file to real file
    cp /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp \
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override

    # compile
    glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
fi

exit 0
```

Save the file and exit the `gedit` editor.

Now mark the script as executable using:

```
chmod +x set-login-wallpaper
```

Open Nautilus and navigate to your directory with wallpaper images. Find an appropriate image and right-click on it. This drop-down menu appears:

[image: Nautilus Right Click Drop Down]

Click on the third option `Scripts`. Another drop down menu appears with all your scripts:

[image: Nautilus set-login-wallpaper Drop Down]

Select `set-login-wallpaper`.

When the script runs you will have to enter your `sudo` password.

Reboot and enjoy your new login and lock screen wallpaper.